# How to navigate to specific path within action in React with Redux application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am new to React with Redux structure and its concept. In my application, I need to navigate specific path in an action after login. My action code is:

```
const login = (resp:Object) => (dispatch: any) =>{
     // api call
     if(apiCall is success){
     window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000"+localStorage.getItem("pathBeforeLogin");
     }
     else{
       window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
    }
  });
}
```

This code is working fine but my senior asked me to do this work without using `window.location.href`. As We are using the react-router v4, browserHistory.push is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

[react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) provides a Redux middleware that allow you to navigate via Redux actions.

From https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';

// Apply the middleware to the store
const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
);

// Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
store.dispatch(push('/foo'));
```

So in your example, instead of assigning strings to window.location.href, you'd do the following:

```
store.dispatch(push('/login'));
```

Comment: It's give me error 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.

Comment: Have you added `redux` and `react-router-redux` to your project? Otherwise, run `npm install redux` and `npm install react-router-redux` in a prompt inside your project directory

Comment: Then `push` should be defined.  Can you confirm you're importing it as shown in the example above?

Comment: Ah, I think you edited you first comment. Ok, so you need to import browserHistory from react-router too

Comment: I also import broserHistory as import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'. But it still gives me error react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151471/discussion-between-kelltontech-and-kim-burgaard).